# Vue Js / Symfony / Api platform Authentication via Session error 401

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I watched the latest symfony cast on api platform and security (chapter 2: API Plateform Security) I'm blocking in chapter 5 (Login Success & the Session) of the latter. When I send a POST request with axios from my Vuejs application with the user's credentials, the API does send me the IRI of my user. Until all is well but when I try to send a GET request to my API to display the information of the user in question it returns me a 401 error because yes I have set up a voting system so that there is only the owner of the data that it draws to access it. So my user is not logged in and I am blocking myself there.

Here is my SecurityController login function:

```
      /**
     * @Route("/api/login", name="api_login", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function login(IriConverterInterface $iriConverter)
    {
        if(!$this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
            return $this->json([
                'error' => 'Invalid login reuqest'
            ], 400);
        }

        return $this->json([
            'location' => $iriConverter->getIriFromItem($this->getUSer())
        ]);
    }
```

Here is my security.yaml :

```
    security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:

        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: api_logout

            stateless: false
            json_login:
                check_path: api_login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
```

And here is the annotation my entity User and my user_voter :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Email existant")
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "GET",
 *          "POST",
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "GET"= {"security" = "is_granted('USER_VOTER', object)"},
 *          "PATCH"= {"security" = "is_granted('USER_VOTER', object)"},
 *          "DELETE"
 *      },
 * )
 */

    
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
    {
        if(!$subject instanceof User){
            return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        if(!in_array('USER_VOTER', $attributes)){
            return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();

        if(!$user instanceof UserInterface){
            return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        if($subject !== $user){
            return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
```

PS: Sorry I started since january on symfony

Answer (score 0):

Use lexik_jwt_authentication for generate jwt token.

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/v1/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login
                username_path: username
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```